# Selenium Webdriver : Not able to select date from datepicker popup while automating Makemytrip.com

Tags: iframe, calendar, datepicker, selenium-webdriver

Warm Greetings!!

I am trying to click on a date value from the data window popped up after clicking on the datepicker but I am getting No Element Found Exception.

I have gone thru all possible solutions present in dis forum but seems none satisfy my need.

Below is the code:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

baseUrl = "http:www.makemytrip.com/flights";    

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

public void testFlip1() throws Exception {

      driver.get(baseUrl + "/");        

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-button-text-only.ui-corner-left.ui-state-active")).click();    

  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".flL:nth-of-type(2)>.ui-combobox>input")).sendKeys("New Delhi, India (DEL)");

  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".flL:nth-of-type(3)>.ui-combobox>input")).sendKeys("Mumbai, India (BOM)");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.date_field_tab.flL.make_relative.left")).click();*

Until here the calender gets expanded and the issue starts next when I am trying to select a date.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[text()='30']")).click();
```

The above xpath works properly in IDE and selects the value.But its not working in webdriver.

Kindly help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue, setting the date Via JavaScript helped.

```
javaScriptExe("$(\"input[Rel='Due Date']\").removeAttr('readonly').removeAttr('hidden').
val('"23 May 2015"')");
```